# How do I install MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb

I am new to Ubuntu (it's has been 25 years since I used UNIX in any significant way). I would like to set up MariaDB on both a desktop and server version of Ubuntu 15.04, and I understand MariaDB is part of the Ubuntu distro management system. What I need is to be directed on how to do it

1. From the GUI, and
2. from command line (for server)

When I tried to follow other instructions I found on this site and others for the desktop: Dash, Software, Ubuntu Software Centre, and typed in Maria it comes back with All Software selected, it came back with 'No items in Our star apps match "Maria". But those instructions did, admittedly, say they were for 14 or 11+ so I guess something changed for 15?

Can you direct me to the best place to understand/learn how to do this I'd appreciate it.